# Finding unit vectors orthogonal to another vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all unit vectors in the plane determined by $u = (3, 0, 1)$ and $v= (1, -1, 1)$ that are orthogonal to the vector $w= (1, 2, 0)$.

Answer: $± \frac{1}{\sqrt {61}} (6, -3, 4)$

Can someone explain the process for me? I understand where the former part $± \frac{1}{\sqrt {61}}$ is from, but I don't understand how you get $(6, -3, 4)$.

Comment: Two vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is $0$. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Hint 1: How do you express a general vector in the plane of the vectors $u$ and $v$? 

Hint 2: What is the condition for orthogonality of two vectors?

Comment: Please take the time to learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In addition, please write more specific titles so that they can be easily searched by others (*AP Calculus AB multiple choice* is a good title).

Comment: ok i will change the title next time!

Comment: I'm curious: how did you find $±\frac{1}{\sqrt {61}}$, but not the rest of the answer?

Comment: I didn't mean i got the answers, but i meant that i understand how you would need to multiply that part to make it into a unit vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer based on Dhanvi's comment.

Any vector in the plane can be represented as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$. This means that for arbitrary reals $a, b$, the vector $a (3,0,1) + b (1, -1, 1) = (3a+b, -b, a+b)$ is in the plane.

The dot product with $w$ is $(3a+b) \cdot 1 + (-b) \cdot 2 + (a+b) \cdot 0 = 3a-b$. From the definition of the dot product, $3a - b =0$.

Since the vector must be a unit vector, $(3a+b)^2 + (-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 = 1$ (why?). Solve this system of equations to find $a$ and $b$:

$$3a-b = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$(3a+b)^2 + (-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 = 1 \tag{2}$$

which does give $a = ±\frac{1}{\sqrt{61}}$, $b = ±\frac{3}{\sqrt{61}}$. Substituting $a$ and $b$ and taking out a factor of $±\frac{1}{\sqrt{61}}$ gives the book's answer.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you got 6, 3, and 4 though :( I get everything until the 3a-b, but what does that have to do with the answer?

Comment: You solve the system of two equations to find $a$ and $b$. Then substitute into the general form, and take out a factor of $±\frac{1}{\sqrt {61}}$. This gives $±\frac{1}{\sqrt{61}} (3(1) + 3, -3, 1 + 3)$.

Comment: Now that you have $a,b$, substitute them into the general form you got from $au + bv$ to get the vector you need

Comment: ok thank you so much! :)